# Using httr2 with OAuth 1.0 Authentication

Tags: r, oauth, httr2

I've been given access to a cool API -- yay!  But the authentication information I've been given doesn't seem to match anything I can find in the httr2 documentation.

I've been given these four values:

Consumer Key
Consumer Secret
Access Token
Token Secret

And a URL: https://api.gunviolencearchive.org/api/incidents.json

The instructions say to include full authentication in the header with each request, and to include a throttle.  There is no time limit, apparently, once a token is obtained.

I am new at this, so please be gentle.

Thanks so much!

I tried the following with httr, because there seems to be more documentation on using httr with Oauth 1.0, but got "request must be signed":

```
library(httr)

headers = c(oauth_consumer_key="###",oauth_token="###",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1709088023",oauth_nonce="pqgWMz9XJG8",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="ISnTuPVk8dtV6xj4%2F8C9BrQ7CYU%3D",
  'Cookie' = 'SSESSadcf082155f3ed84e8258635a32052e6=rmAn_wGCIrk8VvALtc352qXuwGZEG0pYlJvuaYmwnK0'
)

res <- VERB("GET", url = "https://api.gunviolencearchive.org/api/incidents.json?pagesize=40000&filters[IncidentDate][method]=is year&filters[IncidentDate][field][date-year]=2015&truncation_limit=0", add_headers(headers))

cat(content(res, 'text'))
```

Comment: OAuth2 is not a simple mechanism, and cannot be resolved via a one-time header/parameter as `GET` and `POST` provide. Search for `httr2 oauth2` and you should find the package documentation for it, https://httr2.r-lib.org/reference/req_oauth_auth_code.html and the package [`vignette("oauth")`])(https://httr2.r-lib.org/articles/oauth.html).

Comment: Additionally, your title says `httr2` but your code uses `httr`, they are different packages. If you're just starting out, I think the basic guidance (from the authors) might be to go with `httr2`, but there are many functions within the former, accessible via https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/index.html.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding!  My understanding from reading the documentation is that the Oauth protocol in httr2 presumes you have credentials and need to obtain a token.  My understanding of what has happened here is that (possibly unwisely) the maintainer of this API has not given me credentials, instead preferring to just give me a form of token.  There is nothing in the documentation I could parse about what to do when this is the case.

Comment: If I understand it correctly (I am by far not an expert on it), OAuth can be used with username/password and not a token.